# Store a two value combination

Tags: vb.net

I want to store a two value combination but cannot find the right class. I know I could do it with a two dimentional array but is there another way since I always have to do the redimentionalisation. I know about the dictionary but there is the first value always the key.

Example:
I have a dgv and want to collect the rownumbers with duplicates. I iterate throu the dgv and collect 1 and 4, 20 and 33 and so on and store this combinations to use them somewhere else.

Comment: Take a look at KeyValue pair and just have one be the key. Otherwise make a structure yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use collection of [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2). For example :

```
Dim tuples As New List(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer))
tuples.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 4))
tuples.Add(Tuple.Create(20, 33))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be with a Dictionary(Of DataGridViewRow, List(Of Integer)).  The list would contain the rows holding the values in the key.  This will work if you get more than 2 rows trhat are duplicates.